# How to determine age when you have only 6 digits

Tags: android

I`m trying to get the age from a DOB, but the method i use currently requires 8 digits :  26091964. this returns good results.

But the DOB data i get consists of only 6 digits (from passport MRZ : 260964). How can i determine the age from this ?

this is what i have so far:

```
public Integer ageChecker(String dateOfBirth) {
        if (dateOfBirth.length() == 6) {
            if (StringUtils.isNumeric(dateOfBirth)) {
                String year = dateOfBirth.substring(0, 2);
                String month = dateOfBirth.substring(2, 4);
                String day = dateOfBirth.substring(4, 6);


                int dag = Integer.parseInt(day);
                int maand = Integer.parseInt(month);
                int jaar = Integer.parseInt(year);

                Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

                dob.set(jaar, maand, dag);

                int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
                    age--;
                }

                Integer ageInt = new Integer(age);
                  return ageInt;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: With only 6 letters , if suppose dob is 010115 how will you identify age. It can be 1 year or 101  year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [SimpleDateFormat:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

With this format you should parse your date correctly most of the time, since year can not be properly identified by only 2 digits:

```
ddMMyy
```

In case of 8 digits:

```
ddMMyyyy
```